# How to inject an object into a service?

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony-services

I need to do a couple of things:

1. Inject guzzle's httpclient into class A
2. Inject class A into my service

What I've tried so far:

1. ```
   services:
     my_module.field_fetcher:
       class: Drupal\my_module\ClassB
       arguments: ['@my_module.obj', '@logger.factory', '@config.factory']

     my_module.obj:
       class: Drupal\my_module\ClassA
       arguments: ['@http.client']
   ```
2. ```
   parameters:
     my_module.http_client.config:
       base_uri: 'http://myurl.com/'

   services:
     my_module.http_client:
       factory: '@http_client_factory:fromOptions'
       arguments: ['%my_module.http_client.config%']

     my_module.obj:
       class: Drupal\my_module\ClassA
       arguments: ['@my_module.http_client']

     my_module.field_fetcher:
       class: Drupal\my_module\ClassB
       arguments: ['@my_module.obj', '@logger.factory', '@config.factory']
   ```

Simple versions of classes A and B look like this:

ClassA:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

use GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class A {
  
  /**
   * @var \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface
   */
  private $httpClient;
  
  public function __construct(ClientInterface $httpClient) {
    $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
  }
}
```

ClassB:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactory;

class B implements BInterface {
  
  /**
   * @var \Drupal\my_module\A
   */
  private $a;
  
  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactory
   */
  private $logger;

  public function __construct(A $a, LoggerChannelFactory $logger, ConfigFactoryInterface $config) {
    $this->a = $a;
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }
  
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      A::create($container),
      $container->get('my_module.obj'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('my_module'),
      $container->get('config.factory')
    );
  }
}
```

No matter what I try, I keep running into the same issue of drupal error logs telling me that "argument 1 passed to Drupal\my_module\ClassB::__construct() must be an instance of Drupal\my_module\ClassA, string given"

**Edit:** Updated classes A and B to reflect changes suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this `my_module.services.yml` file:

```
services:
  my_module.obj:
    class: Drupal\my_module\ClassA
    arguments: ['@http.client']
```

You can discard the `create()` method from your `A` class, because you declared it as a service for which the arguments get resolved by the services YAML file parameters ie. `'@http_client'`:

```
class A implements AInterface {
  
  /**
   * @var \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface
   */
  private $httpClient;
  
  /**
   * @param \GuzzleHttp\ClientInterface $http_client
   *   A Guzzle client object.
   */
  public function __construct(ClientInterface $http_client) {
    $this->httpClient = $http_client;
  }
```

> argument 1 passed to Drupal\my_module\ClassB::__construct() must be an instance of Drupal\my_module\ClassA, string given

Fix this by correcting your `B` class `create()` method to pass your service `A` name being `'my_module.obj'`, which would then in turn correctly pass an instance to the constructor of class `B`:

```
class B implements ContainerInjectionInterface {
  
  /**
   * @var \Drupal\my_module\AInterface
   */
  private $a;

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Logger\LoggerChannelFactory
   */
  private $logger;

  /**
   * @param \Drupal\my_module\AInterface
   *   Your module A class.
   */
  public function __construct(AInterface $a, LoggerChannelFactory $logger, ConfigFactoryInterface $config) {
    $this->a = $a;
    $this->logger = $logger;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('my_module.obj'),
      $container->get('logger.factory')->get('my_module'),
      $container->get('config.factory')
    );
  }
```

Comment: I updated my original post to reflect the changes you suggested. Now instead of getting an error that argument 1 to the constructor is a string instead of an instance of ClassA, it tells me that argument 1 is an instance of LoggerChannelFactory when it should be an instance of A. It's like it's ignoring the ```$container->get('my_module.obj')``` line in the ```create()``` method.

Comment: Also, which option (1 or 2 from my original post) should I be using for my services.yml file?

Comment: Please use the 1st option from your post, and yes the arguments need to add up with your contructor. For that remaining argument error please discard `A::create($container),` from Class `B`, that is now resolved by `$container->get('my_module.obj')` instead.

Comment: Ohhh duh I should have realized I needed to remove that ```A::create($container),``` part. That fixed it, thank you a ton!